# AdView Admob Error

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

I have seen many similar topics at this forum, but none of them solved my problem.
In my code I have something like this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

...

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And it shows me 2 errors(I marked the red marks as bold text):

-In first line: "AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.**adView**);" - adView cannot be resolved or is not a field

-And in last line: "**adView.loadAd(adRequest)**;" - The type android.view.ViewGroup cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have no idea what causes it. I also had a problem with lack of "layout" folder before, but I generated it with eclipse new>other>android XML layout file. Should I also somehow link it using manifest?

P.S. It's libGDX project

EDIT:
Here is my layout/activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Post your layout file where you are placing the adview

Comment: have you imported google play service library?

Comment: @Ravi Yes, Google play service is imported to my project.

Ranjith, I'll post it up there ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is with this line

```
import com.google.android.gms.R;
```

remove this and import your package .R file

```
import <package name>.R
```

Comment: Hm, how exactly should I import it?
when i try like: "import com.name.game.R", it doesn't work.
My R.java is located in "Project name\android\gen\com\google\android\gms"

Comment: if your packagename.R not working than there are some errors either in your layout or manifest, try to clean you project and check in console for error detail

Comment: Wow, nevermind, I imported android project to core and it works now, but I have a problem here now: "AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);" - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type GameScreen

Comment: GameScreen must extend activity and no need to write "this", just try with findViewById()

Comment: Well, it partly helped, Now I don't have any errors in code but in Problems section i can see a couple of "A cycle was detected in the build path of project" errors. I tried re-checking android and cleaning projects but it didn't work

Comment: Ok, I managed to get rid of that problem, but now, when I run my game, and click "start", it stops with an error...

http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZo98.png

Comment: That error is because of you are changing something in UI from background thread

Comment: What do you mean? I do not use threads in this particular game. When I click start, the game changes screen to "GameScreen" and starts everything. I don't think there are any background threads.

Comment: you are using asynctask, am i right? that is one kind of thread only

Comment: I don't think so... Sorry, I'm kinda newbie in java :(
I'm using libGDX library - maybe it's used in there somewhere...

Comment: Okay, I got rid of all the errors, and the ads are running now :D
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in cocos2dx, I don't have layout file and I want to dislplay admob banner ads, please try this solution without creating layout xml file:

inside `onCreate` function :

```
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("YOUR ID");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        int width = getDisplaySize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()).x;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        addContentView(adView, adParams);
```

and `getDisplaySize` method:

```
// Helper get display screen to avoid deprecated function use
        private Point getDisplaySize(Display d)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                {
                    return getDisplaySizeGE11(d);
                }
                return getDisplaySizeLT11(d);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
            private Point getDisplaySizeGE11(Display d)
            {
                Point p = new Point(0, 0);
                d.getSize(p);
                return p;
            }
            private Point getDisplaySizeLT11(Display d)
            {
                try
                {
                    Method getWidth = Display.class.getMethod("getWidth", new Class[] {});
                    Method getHeight = Display.class.getMethod("getHeight", new Class[] {});
                    return new Point(((Integer) getWidth.invoke(d, (Object[]) null)).intValue(), ((Integer) getHeight.invoke(d, (Object[]) null)).intValue());
                }
                catch (NoSuchMethodException e2) // None of these exceptions should ever occur.
                {
                    return new Point(-1, -1);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e2)
                {
                    return new Point(-2, -2);
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e2)
                {
                    return new Point(-3, -3);
                }
                catch (InvocationTargetException e2)
                {
                    return new Point(-4, -4);
                }
            }
```

Comment: try to import classes, and please define adView as global variable like this AdView adView;

Comment: Well, there are multiple errors. Give me a minute, I'll try to paste them all here

Comment: @urban07 Did you try the solution and please add the error

Comment: Sorry, I think that @Ravi has a better solution, so I'll just use that one (now I got rid from almost all errors)

Comment: OK but I am trying to give you solution if you don't have layout xml file, and  I used this solution in my games,  anyway it's your decision